# Is it possible to build and use syntaxnet for use in a java/C++ app on desktop and or mobile?

Tags: android, ios, tensorflow, jvm, syntaxnet

I managed to lauch syntaxnet and it's tutorial through docker & a juniper notebook

I think that I also managed to build syntaxnet through python and the binary wheels but I have not yet figured how to use it (the documentation is severely lacking)

I have not yet succeeded in building syntaxnet for ubuntu 17.10 from source (lots of errors there).

Is it possible to use the syntaxnet models on mobile through tensorflow only or do we need additionnal (syntaxnet specific) stuff ?

I would like toknow what is possible and what is not possible with syntaxnet (for android, ios, jvm desktop app) to evaluate the feasability of my next project

Best regards,
Olivier